# I can't load my file?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

i'm trying to cast a line in this code to String, but somehow it wont work..
The code wont even open the file.
Here's the code:

```
package javagame;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Terrain {

    public static String test;

    private Scanner x;

    private final File world = new File("World.txt");

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(world);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Coudn't load ''World.txt''");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        try{
            test = x.toString();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Couldn't cast to string");
        }
        System.out.println(test);
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        try{
            x.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Couldn't close file");
        }
    }
}
```

When i run the code i get these error messages:
*Coudn't load ''World.txt''
Couldn't cast to string
null
Couldn't close file*

The file is located the same place as the other files in the main package.

Comment: Don't throw away the error message in that exception; print it out.

Comment: Please add `e.printStackTrace()` to each catch clause...

Comment: I've removed the exceptions, and it now says: java.io.FileNotFoundException: World.txt (The system cannot find the file specified) - I don't really understand why it can't find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely situation is that you are not running the program from the same location as the file you are trying to load. Try using a full path name to the file, or make sure that you run your program in the same directory that the file is located.

In a more complete program, you might specify the file that you want to read as a command line argument or as a system property.